# How can I use a custom skin pore brush to sculpt paint much higher detail?

Tags: image, sculpting, brushes

I am a beginner at this and have been experimenting with creating my own custom skin pore brush in Krita. I've looked up dozens of tutorials on this and I've seen people use very low image sizes for a brush (like 70x70 pixels) and the detail when sculpting in blender came out fantastic. No matter what size image for the brush I export it as, the pores come out huge.

I will then bake the high res model into a low res model.

[image: The skin pore brush I made in Krita]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Do you want the pores to be smaller?

Comment: Yes, I would like the pores to be smaller when painted onto the mesh.